# Binding and Creating scope variables dinamically in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, scope

Context: I am building a helper with dynamically editable help sections (each one with its title and content). I have an "Add" button at the bottom of the last help existing section to add more help sections to this helper. 
I am binding a variable `$scope.helpVisible` to set the visibility of the section to ReadOnly or Editable with `ng-show` and `ng-hide`.

Problem: When I click on "Add" to add a new help section to the helper, I need a new variable to set the visibility of this new element (a div). The problem is that it takes the previous variable to decide the visibility of this new element.

I have tried to create a list `$scope.listOfVilibilities` pushing a new item every time I create a new help section.

How can I create new variables in the scope "on the fly" and bind them in the view?

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE] to show us where exactly you are having difficulty?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating objects into a array and use `ngRepeat` directive to add this new object into view.

for example controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.list = [];

    $scope.add = function(){
        $scope.list.push({value:void(0), disabled: false});
    }
    $scope.delete = function(value){
        $scope.list = _.remove($scope.list, function(n){
        return n.value !== value;
      });
    }
}
```

> Important! I used lodash library in the delete function. [Doc. here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#remove)

The HTML look like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <button ng-click="add()">
  Add
  </button>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="some in list">
      <input ng-model="some.value" ng-disabled="some.disabled"/>
      <button ng-click="some.disabled = !some.disabled">
      {{!some.disabled}}
      </button>
      <button ng-click="delete(some.value)">
      Delete
      </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Take a look to this example live in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ismaleiva90/3x1e8kta/1/).

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much!